# deserialize api response w/newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net, class, json.net, deserialization

I need help deserializing a response.  (I'm making a call to Data247 on a phone number, and the api returns the mobile phone carrier).  The api call is working and I'm getting back a valid response that looks like this:

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": "OK",
        "results": [
            {
                "phone": "11234567890",
                "wless": "y",
                "carrier_name": "Blue Licenses Holding, LLC",
                "carrier_id": 6,
                "sms_address": "1234567890@txt.att.net",
                "mms_address": "1234567890@mms.att.net"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is in a C#.NET winforms app.  To test this, you'd have to have an access key from Data247.  Everything is working through the api call.  My problem is with this line:

```
Data247 data247 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data247>(response.Content);
```

...and so I don't think my class is structured correctly. ...or maybe I'm not deserializing correctly.
  My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace myTest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string request = txtEndpoint.Text;
                request += "?key=" + txtAccessKey.Text;
                request += "&api=CU";
                request += "&phone=" + txtPhone.Text;
                var client = new RestClient(request);
                var response = client.Execute(new RestRequest());
                Data247 data247 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data247>(response.Content);

                MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
                Debug.Print(response.Content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public class Data247
        {
            Response response { get; set; }
            public class Response
            {
                public string status { get; set; }
                Results results { get; set; }

                public class Results
                {
                    List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>();
                    public Phone phone { get; set; }
                    public class Phone
                    {
                        public string phone { get; set; }
                        public string wless { get; set; }
                        public string carrier_name { get; set; }
                        public string carrier_id { get; set; }
                        public string sms_address { get; set; }
                        public string mms_address { get; set; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the recommended trick from @Hirasawa, I believe it's important to understand how all this works, so I would like to point out a couple of glitches in your code.

> You don't need the Phone class.

If you look at the structure of the data, the phone number is only a property of the result item. Also, `Results` is an array, so let's update the code to fix those errors:

```
public class Data247
{
    Response response { get; set; }

    public class Response
    {
        public string status { get; set; }

        public Results[] results { get; set; }

        public class Results
        {
            public string phone { get; set; }
            public string wless { get; set; }
            public string carrier_name { get; set; }
            public string carrier_id { get; set; }
            public string sms_address { get; set; }
            public string mms_address { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

> Target properties must be public.

In order to correctly deserialize the response, the properties in your target classes must be **public**. Fixing those errors we get:

```
public class Data247
{
    public Response response { get; set; }

    public class Response
    {
        public string status { get; set; }

        public Results[] results { get; set; }

        public class Results
        {
            public string phone { get; set; }
            public string wless { get; set; }
            public string carrier_name { get; set; }
            public string carrier_id { get; set; }
            public string sms_address { get; set; }
            public string mms_address { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above changes, the code now works. Well, almost ;-). It turns out that we now have a nested class `Results` at the same level of a property named `Results`. This is not valid in C# and the compiler will let you know that with an error: *"There is already a Results member declared."*.

The fix is easy though, we just move the nested classes to the outer scope or we could rename the `Response` and `Results` classes to something like `ResponseDTO` and `ResultDTO`, but I find the former easier to do. So now our code is:

```
public class Data247
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string status { get; set; }

    public Results[] results { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string wless { get; set; }
    public string carrier_name { get; set; }
    public string carrier_id { get; set; }
    public string sms_address { get; set; }
    public string mms_address { get; set; }
}
```

> BONUS: Write idiomatic C# code.

If you want to write idiomatic code, you should use the recommended property names. This is a matter of style and the code as it is is working, but a C# developer will thank you if your code is properly written.

This is a brief summary of what I'll do:

1. Rename property names to `UpperCamelCase` format. Eg: `mms_address` should be `MmsAddress`.
2. Due to 1. we must also use attributes to map the actual property names in the json to the C# property name.

Below is the final code:

```
public class Data247
{
    [JsonProperty("Response")]
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public Results[] Results { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    [JsonProperty("Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("wless")]
    public string Wless { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("carrier_name")]
    public string CarrierName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("carrier_id")]
    public string CarrierId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sms_address")]
    public string SmsAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mms_address")]
    public string MmsAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!  Karel, your class structured worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

https://dailydotnettips.com/did-you-know-you-can-automatically-create-classes-from-json-or-xml-in-visual-studio/
And this is how you get the (mostly) correct class for any json structure.

Comment: I did not know about that.  Thank you!